# Register decorator which have extra value parameter in constructor

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I have code similar to this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int GetData();
}


public sealed class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public int GetData() => ...
}


public sealed class MyCachedClass : IMyInterface
{
    public MyCachedClass(IMyInterface myInterface, TimeSpan cacheDuration)
    { ... }

    public int GetData()
    {
        int? data = GetDataFromCache();

        if (data == null)
        {
             data = myInterface.GetData();
             UpdateCache(data);
        }

        return data.Value
    }
}
```

Now I can just simply register MyClass using:

```
container.Register<IMyInterface, MyClass>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Then I want to add decorator to every IMyInterface instance.

```
container.RegisterDecorator<IMyInterface, MyCachedClass>(...);
```

Unfortunately it will not work, because of `TimeSpan cacheDuration` parameter in constructor. I cannot find any overload for this.

Is there a method something like this?:

```
container.RegisterDecorator<IMyInterface>
    (instance => new MyCachedClass(instance, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

**EDIT**: Marked as duplicate? The other question contains answer which turns configuration parameter into new dependency... So it does not answer my question.

Comment: The duplicate does answer your question because wrapping the configuration value into a Parameter Object *is* the solution. This is the advised approach for *any* DI Container.

Comment: @Steven: No. This is not real answer. Looks like simple injector does not have this functionality.

Comment: Simple Injector's philosophy is to steer you to best practice. This is one of them. But there are other options to choose from; Markus described on. And you can override the IDependencyInjectionBehavior. Or you can simply extract the value into a Parameter Object, which is the advised approach.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is primarily that you need to inject a value type into the constructor of the decorator. In order to solve this, you need to create the service with a factory method, e.g.:

```
container.Register<IMyInterface>(() =>
{
    var decorated = container.GetInstance<MyClass>();
    return new MyCachedClass(decorated, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));
});
```

In order to get the decorated class, you can use the container to resolve the dependencies. However, you cannot use `IMyInterface` to resolve the decorated service as this would result in a loop. Though it would be better to use an interface, it is still just one spot in code that you need to change if you want to use a type other than `MyClass`.

Comment: Where `TimeSpan cacheDuration` is set?

Comment: @apocalypse I've extended the post on how to create the decorator dynamically usign a method.

Comment: But your are creating `var instance = new MyClass();` inline... Of course this class may contain its own dependencies which should be injected by container.